# htaccess file causes recursion

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, joomla, system-administration

Website I am trying to setup has such a structure

```
website.com
---category1
------subcategory1
------subcategory2
------subcategory3
------subcategory4
---category2
------subcategory1
------subcategory2
------subcategory3
------subcategory4
---category3
------subcategory1
------subcategory2
------subcategory3
------subcategory4
---category4
------subcategory1
------subcategory2
------subcategory3
------subcategory4
```

When I visit the example.com - it shows me all 4 categories as intended.
When I choose any of the categories - the page is redirected to example.com/shop/index.php/index.php/index.php...
The apache document root folder is /var/www/html/shop

However when i explicitly go to example.com/categoryN page does show up.
The same problem with subcategories.

Here is the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]


RewriteBase /      //I put # in front of it, got no change
writeRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

How can I make this thing work? 
Thanks.

Comment: So you have `/var/www/html/shop/index.php`? I'm pretty sure the issue is that you have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php` which says if the uri doesnt start with index.php add it. where as you probably want if it doesn't end with index.php `!/index\.php$`

Comment: @chris85, yes, there is /var/www/html/shop/index.php file. I tried to replace that condition with `!/index\.php$` but still got the same error.

Comment: I copied your code over to my server and am not having the issues I thought you'd be having. I removed `      //I put # in front of it, got no change` and added `re` to the `writeRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`. After that works as expected, is that your whole file? I have `/public_html/sfo` with `index.php` and `.htaccess` inside then `/public_html/sfo/abc/` with `index.php`. Is this your structure?

Comment: @chris85, the CMS is joomla, so the website structure doesn't equal to the filesystem one. The .htaccess only has one more string I didn't show: `Options +FollowSymLinks`. Here's the ip of the server 128.199.38.61 to make it more visual.

Comment: Where can I see the redirect/rewrite loop?

Comment: @chris85, click on any of the vertical sections - it will try to open the category.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71416/discussion-between-cre8eve-and-chris85).

Comment: I can't reproduce it consistently. For example this execution path worked once, then looped for me, then third time worked. http://128.199.38.61/ -> http://128.199.38.61/kuhni -> http://128.199.38.61/kuhni/kuhnya1

Answer (score 0):

The problem was broken urls in the code.